# How to get Url change from CustomTabsClient

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs

How to get the url when the page changes, using `CustomTabsClient`?

For example WebView has a method:

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon){}
```

I need a similar method for `CustomTabs`.

I have found this one:

```
mClient.newSession(new CustomTabsCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onNavigationEvent(int navigationEvent, Bundle extras) {
        super.onNavigationEvent(navigationEvent, extras);
    }

    @Override
    public void extraCallback(String callbackName, Bundle args) {
        super.extraCallback(callbackName, args);
    }
});
```

But I am not sure if this is the one I need.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> How to get the url when the page changes, using `CustomTabsClient`?

Unfortunately you can't. There is also an open issue on the Chromium bug tracker:

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=543542

The only thing you can do now is to know when the tab has started or finished to loading the page, but you can't retrieve the URL:

```
mClient.newSession(new CustomTabsCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onNavigationEvent(int navigationEvent, Bundle extras) {
        Log.w(TAG, "onNavigationEvent: Code = " + navigationEvent);

        switch (navigationEvent) {
            case NAVIGATION_STARTED:
                // Sent when the tab has started loading a page.
                break;
            case NAVIGATION_FINISHED:
                // Sent when the tab has finished loading a page.
                break;
            case NAVIGATION_FAILED:
                // Sent when the tab couldn't finish loading due to a failure.
                break;
            case NAVIGATION_ABORTED:
                // Sent when loading was aborted by a user action before it finishes like clicking on a link
                // or refreshing the page.
                break;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Has anyone gotten onNavigationEvent to actually get called?  I tried setting this up multiple times but it never seems to get called and I verified it gets set in the .newSession() call :-P

Comment: @kenyee Did you create your chrome intent by passing in the session returned from #newSession()? new CustomTabsIntent.Builder(session);

Comment: That was it @sfreeman...thanks much :-)
They should just require builder take the session for a param.

Comment: @Mattia i have pass the session in Builder also but this onNavigationEvent(...)  never seems to get called even a single time

Comment: If URL is not exposed then what is the use of it??

Comment: Anybody know what is the purpose of bundle argument?